# How do you select an object with lowest property linq query syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to use query syntax to loop through a list of objects and select the object with the lowest int on it's UnitPrice property.

```cs
var lowPrice = from l in DataLoader.LoadProducts()
               group l by l.Category into newGroup
               select new
               {
                    cat = newGroup.Key,
                    lowest = from p in newGroup
                             where p.UnitPrice < p.UnitPrice
                             select p
               };
```

The code above should select a single object with the lowest value in UnitPrice property and store it into the lowest property.

But I do not know the correct syntax for choosing the object with the lowest UnitPrice.

Here's an example of my product objects.  There are a lot of products with the same category.  My objective is to display the category name and the product under that category that has the lowest UnitPrice.  There are a total of 6 categories I believe.

```cs
new Product
                        {
                            ProductID = 1,
                            ProductName = "Chai",
                            Category = "Beverages",
                            UnitPrice = 18.0000M,
                            UnitsInStock = 39
                        },
                        new Product
                        {
                            ProductID = 2,
                            ProductName = "Chang",
                            Category = "Beverages",
                            UnitPrice = 19.0000M,
                            UnitsInStock = 17
                        },
                        new Product
                        {
                            ProductID = 3,
                            ProductName = "Aniseed Syrup",
                            Category = "Condiments",
                            UnitPrice = 10.0000M,
                            UnitsInStock = 13
                        },
                        new Product
                        {
                            ProductID = 4,
                            ProductName = "Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning",
                            Category = "Condiments",
                            UnitPrice = 22.0000M,
                            UnitsInStock = 53
                        },
```

Comment: Do you mean lowest price per category? If you just want lowest try this and see if it works: `(from l in DataLoader.LoadProducts() select l.UnitPrice).Min();`

Comment: I'm looking at selecting the object that has the lowest UnitPrice and not the price itself.

Comment: The normal way it is done is to order by Unit Price before doing the group.  Then the lower price will be the First() item in the group.

Comment: Then order by unit price and take `FirstOrDefault`. It doesn't sound like you need to group.

Comment: What is `DataLoader.LoadProducts()`? It makes a big difference if this is LINQ to objects or LINQ to a SQL backend. Either way, there are many duplicates of your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to select single object with lowest price in each category, here's the solution:

```
var lowestPriceCategories = DataLoader.LoadProducts()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Category = x.Key,
        LowestPrice = x.OrderBy(y => y.UnitPrice).FirstOrDefault()
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Yurii for your suggestion.  It seems to work just fine. I just have to use query syntax for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for you support.  I was able to create something I believe does what I need it to using what you all suggested.

```cs
var lowPrice = from l in DataLoader.LoadProducts()
                           group l by l.Category into newGroup
                           select new
                           {
                               cat = newGroup.Key,
                               lowest = (from p in newGroup
                                         orderby p.UnitPrice
                                        select p).First()
                           };
```

And the result

```cs
foreach (var p in lowPrice)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{p.cat} {p.lowest.ProductName}");
            }
```

Comment: Not to confuse the issue, but do you care if there is more than one item with the same lowest price?

Comment: I guess that's a good point.  What if there are a few items with the same lowest price?  How would I fix that?

Comment: You would have to query for all items with the price that equals the lowest price. Then you would end up with a sequence for each group instead of a single item for each group so then you have to decide how to present it or how your business logic might change.

Comment: Thanks Crowcoder, You've been a big help.  I'll look into selecting all objects with the same lowest price.